# Where am I going wrong with this naïve derivation of the Fourier transform of cos(x)?

Tags: fourier-transform

When I naively attempt to compute the Fourier transform of cos(t) using the definition of the transform I end up with a limit as t goes to infinity involving sin(a*t).  I can see how the Dirac-delta function and exponential form of cos(t) lead to a nice solution but I'm wondering where I'm going wrong.[image: Derivation attempt by hand.]

Comment: Does the integral converge?

Comment: I guess I'm asking whether it's necessary to invoke the Dirac-delta function.  Can we take x to be a complex variable to get to something that does converge or some other strategy like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you integrate across a finite interval and then set the integration limits to infinity, those sincs that you obtained [will converge to the Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function#Relationship_to_the_Dirac_delta_distribution) in distribution.  They do not converge in the ordinary sense.

Comment: But we don't end up with sinc(f(x)) as far as I can tell.  I'm pretty confident the indefinite integral is correct.  Please point out the step where I went wrong if that's the case.

Comment: Let the integration limits be $\pm 1/a$ and $y = 2\omega + 1/\pi$. Then your first fraction evaluated at the upper limit is $\sin(\pi y/a)/(\pi y)$ and converges to $\delta(y)$ when the integration limits tend to infinity ($a \rightarrow 0$).

Comment: Thank you!  That's very illuminating.  Especially for getting a better handle on the Dirac delta function.

Comment: @RubberTrucky The Dirac Delta is NOT a function.  It is a distribution.  And the limitiing process described in the link of this solution is different from an "ordinary" limit.